# Vertical align text

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I can't vertical align a piece of text inside my footer with `vertical-align` properly, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I put the text in a container named `vertical-text` but that didn't fixed anything.

HTML

```
<footer>
    <div class="vertical-text">
    <p>Text that i want to align</p>
    </div>
    <div id="social-img-wrap">
        <h5>Stay connected</h5> 
        <a href=""><img src="img/fb.png" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/gplus.png" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/tw.png" /></a>
    </div>           
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height:auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 29px black;
}

footer p {
    font-size:12px;
    padding-right:10px;
}


footer .vertical-text p {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Thank you in advance !

EDIT : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vuy2vbq5/)

Comment: Please add fiddle. as images are broken. So cannot get exact view.! :(

Comment: sorry for that i added a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vuy2vbq5/

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't find any issue.! how you want it to look like.?

Comment: i want the text on the left on aligned verticaly at the middle of the footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use     `align-items: center;` in `footer` & no need to mention `vertical-align` property

```css
footer {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height:auto;
      align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 29px black;
}

footer p {
    font-size:12px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="vertical-text">
    <p>Made by @EduardValentin</p>
    </div>
    <div id="social-img-wrap">
        <h5>Stay connected</h5> 
        <a href=""><img src="img/fb.png" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/gplus.png" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/tw.png" /></a>
    </div>           
</footer>
```

Comment: So please accept the answer it will help others also